How can I connect to a speaker using SIP?
I successfully connected two speakers using SIP and RTP communication with the PyVoip library in Python.
However, when I set the audio codec to PCMU and the bitrate to 8000 using FFmpeg, the speakers produced noise and the audio quality was poor.
So, I tried various methods to improve the audio quality. I wanted to use PJSIP and Linphone, but I am not sure how to proceed.
I would like to know if there is a Python library that can transmit computer sounds and send microphone input to a speaker. Additionally, I would appreciate step-by-step instructions on how to achieve this.
Here is the code I wrote:
import time
import threading
import subprocess
import multiprocessing
from pyVoIP.VoIP import VoIPPhone, CallState

# 기본 설정
CHUNK = 1024
CHANNELS = 1
RATE = 8000

def transmit_audio(phone :VoIPPhone, number:int, stream_in) :
    try:
        call_id = phone.call(number)

        while call_id.state != CallState.ANSWERED:
            time.sleep(1)

        while True:
            data = stream_in.recv()
            call_id.write_audio(data)
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
    finally :
        """
        종료기간 설정 필요
        stop = time.time() + (frames / 8000)
        while time.time() <= stop and call_id.state == CallState.ANSWERED:
            time.sleep(0.1)
        """
        call_id.hangup()
        phone.stop()

def tee(input_stream, output_stream1, output_stream2):
    def fanout():
        while True:
            data = input_stream.read(4096)  
            if not data:
                break
            output_stream1.send(data)
            output_stream2.send(data)
        output_stream1.close()
        output_stream2.close()
    
    threading.Thread(target=fanout, daemon=True).start()

def main() :
    # ffmpeg 프로그램 명령어
    options = ["ffmpeg"]
    options.append("-f")
    options.append("dshow")
    options.append("-i")
    options.append("audio=Stereo Mix(Realtek(R) Audio)")
    options.append("-filter:a")
    options.append("volume=3")
    options.append("-f")
    options.append("wav")
    options.append("-acodec")
    options.append("pcm_u8")
    options.append("-ar")
    options.append(str(RATE))
    options.append("-ac")
    options.append(str(CHANNELS))
    options.append("-y")
    options.append("pipe:1")

    ffmpeg_process1 = subprocess.Popen(
        options,
        stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
    )

    # 두 개의 파이프 생성
    parent_conn1, child_conn1 = multiprocessing.Pipe(duplex=False)
    parent_conn2, child_conn2 = multiprocessing.Pipe(duplex=False)
    
    # ffmpeg stdout을 두 파이프로 복제
    tee(ffmpeg_process1.stdout, child_conn1, child_conn2)

    phone1=VoIPPhone("192.168.5.200", 5060, "admin", "admin", sipPort=5060)
    phone1.start()

    phone2=VoIPPhone("192.168.5.201", 5060, "admin", "admin", sipPort=5061)
    phone2.start()

    thread1 = threading.Thread(target=transmit_audio, args=(phone1, 6001, parent_conn1,))
    thread1.start()

    thread2 = threading.Thread(target=transmit_audio, args=(phone2, 6002, parent_conn2,))
    thread2.start()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()

To transmit sound to a speaker using SIP in Python
